# How to send Angular 8 Form Data in this JSON Format? How to build a Nested JSON to send over HTTP post request?

Tags: json, angular, http, post, nested

My JSON is in this format. How do you design a Angular FormGroup for this to get and update this data easily. I am facing issues with writing a good structure for form group.

If the JSON structure is complex please suggest changes.

```
{
usertypes_id: "1",
name: "Admin",
permissions: "{"dashboard":{"name":"Dashboard","value":"Full"},"studioInformation":{"name":"Studio Information","value":"Full"},"studioLocation":{"name":"Studio Location","value":"Full"},"users":{"name":"Users","value":"Full"},"roles":{"name":"Roles","value":"Full"},"dancers":{"name":"Dancers","value":"Full"},
},
{
usertypes_id: "2",
name: "Staff",
permissions: "{"dashboard":{"name":"Dashboard","value":"Full"},"studioInformation":{"name":"Studio Information","value":"Full"},"studioLocation":{"name":"Studio Location","value":"Full"},"users":{"name":"Users","value":"Full"},"roles":{"name":"Roles","value":"Full"},"dancers":{"name":"Dancers","value":"Full"},
}
```

This is what I have already tried

```
constructor(
    private rolesService: RolesService,
    private menuItems: MenuItems,
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) {

  }

ngOnInit() {
 const name = this.fb.control("", [Validators.required]);
    const permissions = this.fb.group({
      dashboard: this.fb.group({
        name: ["", Validators.required],
        value: ["", Validators.required]
      }),
      studioInformation: this.fb.group({
        name: ["", Validators.required],
        value: ["", Validators.required]
      }),
      studioLocation: this.fb.group({
        name: ["", Validators.required],
        value: ["", Validators.required]
      }),
      users: this.fb.group({
        name: ["", Validators.required],
        value: ["", Validators.required]
      }),
      roles: this.fb.group({
        name: ["", Validators.required],
        value: ["", Validators.required]
      }),
      dancers: this.fb.group({
        name: ["", Validators.required],
        value: ["", Validators.required]
      }),
      staff: this.fb.group({
        name: ["", Validators.required],
        value: ["", Validators.required]
      }),
      courses: this.fb.group({
        name: ["", Validators.required],
        value: ["", Validators.required]
      }),
      classes: this.fb.group({
        name: ["", Validators.required],
        value: ["", Validators.required]
      }),
    });

    this.roleForm = this.fb.group({
      name: name,
      permissions: permissions
    })
}
```

Comment: Could you add what you've already tried ?

Comment: @Nicolas This is what I have tried ... Not sure though

Comment: @Nicolas Please look into this

Comment: I'm not sure what to answer here. I'm no expert in Angular and I feel like we are missing some info. You want to update a json according ot a file. Is the file save on the browser or on the server ? If it's on the server, you need an API to update it.

Comment: There is more to this than what you provided.